# Full Text Search on iOS5, iOS6 Unicode (Russian, Japanese, Chinese, Korean)

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, unicode, full-text-search

I need to search within 2.000.000 database rows containing titles e.g. Songs. I need a solution that provides results fast, works on the iOS platform and supports the unicode charset. I am *thinking* about using sqlite's FTS to solve my problem. I am open for any other solutions.

### This is what I know so far:

**Assumption 1:** FTS is enabled by default in iOS >= 5 - this is fine, my minimum requirement is 5

**Assumption 2:** I assume, that unicode folding (Ä => a) does not work without compiling sqlite on my own

**Assumption 3:** I know that FTS does not support substring searches like `MATCH "*searchterm*"`

**Assumption 4:** I read that the default porter stemmer is pretty bad with unicode charsets (Russian, Japanese, Chinese, ...)

My current approach is using `LIKE "%searchterm%"` statements, because they work best with the languages above. Unfortunately they tend to be slow sometimes.

### Questions

**Question 1:** Is sqlite with FTS the right way to go? Or should investigate in cLucene / CoreData, etc? What are the other options? What is the best way to search through titles in different languages on the iOS platform?

**Question 2:** Do I need to replace the tokenizer? Can I load the tokenizer as an extension on the iOS platform? Might [this](https://github.com/littlesavage/sqlite3-unicodesn/blob/master/fts3_unicodesn.c) be the solution?

**Question 3:** Is sqlite fts enabled with the ICU extensions on iOS 5 / 6?

**Question 4:** How does Apple's internal search work e.g. in the music player? CoreData?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check this: [Full Text Search w/ Core Data](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?page_id=1194)

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled upon this article as well, unfortunately it is outdated (from 2009). At this time there was no FTS in iOS so the only possibility was to compile on your own. 

But still, even compiling on my own leaves my questions open.

Comment: Any update on this? I want to use sqlite fts but need unicode